# Set layout visible xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have two activities.

One pass attributes to another.

Code of passing

```
add.Click += delegate {
            var intent = new Intent (this, typeof(CartActivity));
            intent.PutExtra ("title", (string)(firstitem ["post_title"]));
            intent.PutExtra ("price", (string)(firstitem ["price"] + " грн"));
            intent.PutExtra ("weight", (string)(firstitem ["weight"] + "г"));

            StartActivity (intent);
        };
```

Code of receiving

```
private void Display (){

        LinearLayout display = FindViewById<LinearLayout> (Resource.Id.linearLayout13);         
        TextView productname = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.posttittle);
        TextView price = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.price);
        TextView weight = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.weight);
        productname.Text = Intent.GetStringExtra("title");
        price.Text = Intent.GetStringExtra("price");
        weight.Text = Intent.GetStringExtra("weight");

    }
```

And i have block, where I write this attributes, but it hidden.

How i can make it visible when attributes wrote in this block?

Answer (score 2):

I assume display is your block so it should be like this in Xamarin

```
display.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
```

From android's native

```
display.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```